# Zurb Foundation 6 - how to stop the pagination items from being hidden on the small screen?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

How can I turn off foundation's pagination or stop it from hiding my pagination items on small screens?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compressed CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css">

<!-- Compressed JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="pagination text-center" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
    <li class="current"><span class="show-for-sr">You're on page</span> 1</li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 4">4</a></li>
    <li class="ellipsis"></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 12">12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 13">13</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
  });
</script>
```

If you view the default pagination on a small screen, it will on show you **the first and the last items**. But I want **all** items to be displayed even on the small screen, just like in Bootstrap. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

optionally wrapping it in a [media query](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/media-queries.html) if you prefer to only force it on small screens.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compressed CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css">

<!-- Compressed JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<style>
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="pagination text-center" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
    <li class="current"><span class="show-for-sr">You're on page</span> 1</li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 4">4</a></li>
    <li class="ellipsis"></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 12">12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-label="Page 13">13</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
  });
</script>
```